# Symmetric mapping

Tags: calculus

Is there a function such that

$$
f(x,y) = f(y,x)= z \quad \text{for all }x\in\mathbb{R},y\in\mathbb{R}
$$
but not other $x$ or $y$ mapping to the same $z$.

For example, the function $f(x,y) = x+y+xy+x^2+y^2$ would not be the case since:

$$
f(62,3) = f(3,62) =  4104
$$

but also

$$
f(24,48) = f(48,24) =  4104
$$
so both, $(24,48)$ and $(62,3)$ satisfies the first condition but not a unique mapping to $z$.

Is there a function that satisfy both conditions?

PS: If $x\in\mathbb{Z},y\in\mathbb{Z}$ would be great too.

Answer (score 0):

1. Define a bijection $b_1$ from $A = \{(x, y) \mid x < y\}$ to $(0, 1)$.
2. Define a bijection $b_2$ from $D = \{(x, y) \mid x = y\}$ to $(1, 2)$.
3. Define $f$ as $$
   f(x, y) = \begin{cases}
   b_1(x, y) &; x < y \\
   b_1(y, x) &; x > y \\
   b_2(x, y) &; x = y
   \end{cases}
   $$

Comment: Would you please provide an example of $f(x,y)$?

Comment: @VMO You can first try with $x, y\in \mathbb{Z}$ and map $A$ and $D$ bijectively (or injectively) to positive and negative integers respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\varphi\colon\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2\mid y\geqslant x\}\longrightarrow\Bbb R$ be an injective function; such a function exists, since $\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2\mid y\geqslant x\}$ and $\Bbb R$ have the same cardinal. Now, define$$\begin{array}{rccc}f\colon&\Bbb R^2&\longrightarrow&\Bbb R\\&(x,y)&\mapsto&\begin{cases}\varphi(x,y)&\text{ if }y\geqslant x\\\varphi(y,x)&\text{ otherwise.}\end{cases}\end{array}$$

Comment: Would you please provide an example of $\varphi(x,y)$?

Comment: Yes, I could, but it would be a long and not illuminating definition. What's the point?

Comment: If the function that satisties both conditions in a simple way, meaning it does not diverge for large values of $x$ and/or $y$ then I think it solves [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/given-an-array-of-pairs-find-all-symmetric-pairs-in-it/) problem in new way.